# Why is ```print``` not working inside for loop and variables are not changing in Python?

Tags: python, function, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, user-defined-functions

I'm new to Python and I'm working on something that I believe is quite simple. I'm just trying to do some grid search regarding the regularization parameter of a LASSO model using Python's Skicit Learn.

Say I have the following ddataframe (showing only a couple lines and a few columns):

```
notnull_df = 

   AsianPerCap  FemalePctDiv  HispPerCap  HousVacant  LandArea  \
0         0.27          0.75        0.41        0.21      0.12   
1         0.30          0.91        0.35        0.02      0.02   
2         0.29          0.71        0.39        0.01      0.01   
3         0.25          0.49        0.44        0.01      0.02   
4         0.74          0.20        0.48        0.01      0.04   

   LemasPctOfficDrugUn  
0                 0.32  
1                 0.00  
2                 0.00  
3                 0.00  
4                 0.00  


Learning_Y =

0    0.20
1    0.67
2    0.43
3    0.12
4    0.03
```

I have the following:

```
# Defining a way to evaluate models
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error

def evaluate(y_true, y_pred, verbose = False):
    R2 = r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
    MSE = mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
    if verbose == True:
        print('R2: {}'.format(r2_score(y_true, y_pred)))
        print('MSE: {}'.format(mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)))
        print('---')
    return R2, MSE

# Defining a Kfold cross-validation scheme
n_splits = 10
kf = KFold(n_splits, shuffle = True)

# We will fool around with Lasso first
splits = kf.split(notnull_df)
clf = Lasso(alpha = 0.0001, random_state = 0)
R2_Lasso = np.zeros((n_splits, 1))
MSE_Lasso = np.zeros((n_splits, 1))
idx = 0
for train_idx, cv_idx in splits:
    X_train = notnull_df.iloc[train_idx]
    X_cv = notnull_df.iloc[cv_idx]
    Y_train = Learning_Y.iloc[train_idx]
    Y_cv = Learning_Y.iloc[cv_idx]
    clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    Y_pred = clf.predict(X_cv)
    R2, MSE = evaluate(Y_cv, Y_pred, verbose = True)
    R2_Lasso[idx] = R2;
    MSE_Lasso[idx] = MSE;
    idx = idx + 1
```

This works fine, even the verbose part. It will generate the `R2_Lasso` and `MSE_Lasso` arrays as I need. Now comes the trouble. Consider the following implementation of a grid search for the regularization parameter:

```
l1_alpha = [0.00001, 0.00003, 0.0001, 0.0003, 0.001, 0.003, 0.01, 0.3, 1, 3, 10]
avg_R2 = np.zeros((len(l1_alpha), 1))
avg_MSE = np.zeros((len(l1_alpha), 1))
R2_Lasso = np.zeros((n_splits, 1))
MSE_Lasso = np.zeros((n_splits, 1))
for i, alpha in enumerate(l1_alpha):
    clf = Lasso(alpha)
    idx = 0
    for train_idx, cv_idx in splits:
        X_train = notnull_df.iloc[train_idx]
        X_cv = notnull_df.iloc[cv_idx]
        Y_train = Learning_Y.iloc[train_idx]
        Y_cv = Learning_Y.iloc[cv_idx]
        clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
        Y_pred = clf.predict(X_cv)
        R2, MSE = evaluate(Y_cv, Y_pred, verbose = False)
        print(R2)    # I added this line after my problem started
        R2_Lasso[idx] = R2
        MSE_Lasso[idx] = MSE
        idx = idx + 1

    avg_R2[i] = np.mean(R2_Lasso)
    avg_MSE[i] = np.mean(MSE_Lasso)
```

It's basically the same code as before. I would like, on each run, to compute two arrays as before and, now, to take the average.

PROBLEM: when I ask Jupyter Notebook to run it, the `R2_Lasso` vector is ALWAYS zero on every entry and also is `MSE_Lasso`. I tried on Spyder and on Atom and had the same problem. Obviously, when I ask for means, it's all zero.

I have checked and the iteration on `i` and `alpha` is running fine, its really iterating. However it won't print anything, even if I specify `verbose = True`. It won't, for example, print `R2` either. I added this line just to make sure it would (or not!) print it. Really strange. Is this a silly question? Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot in advance!!!!

---

**EDIT**: I'm providing a screenshot of the results of the cell on Jupyter notebook:

[image]

As I said, it will print `i` correctly but won't print, let's say, `R2` on any iteration, although I have asked for it (for debugging purposes).

Comment: There are a few things about your post that make it hard to help you.  (1) It's not clear how your two code blocks go together.  The second can't be a replacement of the first, as there is no definition of `splits`.  Please clarify.  (2) It's not easy to debug code without any example data to work with.  Can you give a toy example dataset to work on?  (3) I's not clear what you mean when you refer to `it`, eg `it won't print anything`, `its really iterating`.  Please be specific.  (4) Are you sure the `for...splits` loop is behaving as expected?  Provide `print` output if possible.

Comment: I'm sorry @andrew_reece. First, the blocs are not substitute. I would like to use the first and then motivate some grid search textually, preceding to the last code block afterwards. That's why I haven't bothered redefining ```splits```. What I want to say is that if we ask for it to print ```i``` at the end, it will print the correct values, really iterating over the enumeration of the list. But it seems it's not running the inner the loop.

Comment: Is it clearer now @andrew_reece? Thanks so much in advance!